# Ajax Post request fails

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am sending a http POST request to a php file (*located in another host*), using ajax, inside a JavaScript file hosted at 000webhost.com.
Even though I can see that the php file at the other host gets my request and acts accordingly, my script believes that the request failed and moves to the ***`fail(function()`*** part of the code.

Could this be a problem with my host?

Here is the code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'MyURL',
    data: 'MyData',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json'
}).done(function(jqxhr){
    //Part which I want to be executed.
}).fail(function(){
    //Part which that is executed.
}).always(function(){

});
```

Comment: Have you looked at your JavaScript error console? Or looked at the error argument that gets passed to your fail callback?

Answer (score -1):

you need to set **crossDomain** to true for cross domain requests. look here for more information

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: You should read your own link: *If you wish to force a crossDomain request (such as JSONP) on the same domain, set the value of crossDomain to true. This allows, for example, server-side redirection to another domain.*